# IE7 line-height

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

My nav bar in ie7 is completely messing up. First image is what it should look like in chrome, second in ie7. The line-height is set at 0.3, and I can change it so it works in ie7, but then it doesn't work in any other browsers. Any solutions for this? Image link below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cpj8.png]

Comment: Nobody could even begin to tell you how to solve this without seeing your code.  Otherwise, this is all guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [conditional CSS statement](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to set the line height to whatever's required for IE7:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
  .selector{line-height:0.5;} // Or whatever line height you need
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Other browsers will just take the default from your normal CSS file/style tags. The code should go in the `<head>` section of the document, after you've linked in/defined your other styles.

Answer (score 1):

If you are floating elements beware of the double margin bug for IE.  to fix simply add a `display: inline` to the floated elements.  This won't break any other browser because a floated element is supposed to be inline.

Comment: Not applicable here.  Double-margin bug is IE 5 & 6 only and the OP is having problems in IE 7.